# Problem with filling missing values in hourly data

Tags: r, time-series

I have hourly data in the format: `"2017-04-01 21:00:00"`. I am deleting all duplicates and then creating a tsibble out of my data.

```
datafilteredtsibble = datafiltered%>% mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))%>%tsibble(index = date_time)
```

This works perfectly fine and at that point I have no NAs nor duplicates or infinite values, just a few gaps. After calling a function:

```
gaps =  count_gaps(datafilteredtsibble)
sum(gaps$.n)
sum(duplicated(datafilteredts$date_time))
```

I have 1012 gaps in time. After calling a function:

```
data = fill_gaps(datafilteredtsibble)
```

I have more than 7000 NAs. Moreover, when I use function:

```
fill(data, .direction="up")
```

nothing happens and I cannot use modelling for time series data. Anyone know how to fix that problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your problem? Maybe a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

The `fill_gaps()` function from `{tsibble}` that you are using allows you to specify what the new values should be (instead of `NA`).

For example, if you had a numeric column called `sales` which is missing when no sales are made in that hour:

```r
data = fill_gaps(datafilteredtsibble, sales = 0)
```

Next time, please provide a minimally reproducible example. It makes it easier to provide answers which are relevant to your problem (rather than me making up an example with 'sales').